# I want to connect my function to reduce the quantity in the stock. The other example availbe on stackoverflow was confusing to me

Tags: javascript, function, cart

I am a junior developer seeking some help. I have written the code below and am trying to add a code that will reduce the quantity in stock. Toward the end of the code I wrote stock[item]-1; but it doesn't reduce the amount in the stock. `

```
const stock = { 
    "banana": 6, 
    "apple": 0,
    "pear": 12,
    "orange": 32,
    "blueberry":1
}  

const prices = {    
    "banana": 4, 
    "apple": 2, 
    "pear": 1,
    "orange": 1.5,
    "blueberry":10
} 

const shoppingList = ["banana","orange","apple"];

function howMuch(){
    let total =0;
    for(let i=0; i<shoppingList.length; i++){
        let item = shoppingList[i];
        if(item in stock){
            if(stock[item]>0){
                total+=prices[item];
                stock[item]-1;
            }   else { console.log(`Sorry we don't have ${item}`);}
        } console.log(total);
    }
}
howMuch();
```

Why doesn't the stock[item]-1; not work. I tried writing
But when I checked it in the console.log with stock.banana the quantity remained at 6.

After that I wrote
stock = stock[item]-1;
And got an error in the debugger.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

What I needed to do was to change the variable to be
stock[item]= stock[item]-1;

Where previously I wrote only
stock[item]-1;
this didn't change the quantity in stock but it wasn't attributed to the variable.

By changing the variable to equal stock[item]-1 it decreases the value of the item.

Thank you for helping.